# How to keep Popup window opened when orientation changes at run time in Android?

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have created a Popup window which contains month view to pick up date. When I changes orientation, due to Android loads an activity all over again my popup Window gets disappears. How can I make it opened even when orientation changes at runtime?

Comment: you can also read this http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

include `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your **AndroidManifest.xml** to the activity displaying window. Doing this tells android that you are going to handle orientation change yourself and eventually it will not destroy your activity and keeping the window displayed.

This technique is good if you dont have different layouts for portrait and landscape mode. However, if you do, you may still perform custom layout implementation by detecting the orientation mode as below:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        Log.i("orientation", "Orientation changed to: Landscape");
    else
        Log.i("orientation", "Orientation changed to: Portrait");
}
```

for preview, download and install [this sample app](http://www.speedyshare.com/file/pan48/HelloWorld.apk).

Comment: are you having two different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations? because I just tested this on single xml layout for both orientations and it worked fine

Comment: hmm strange, because i tested it on a single layout and it works fine. See my demo apk at http://www.2shared.com/file/LdtQTybl/HelloWorld.html

Comment: it even works with **PopupWindow** too. See my new example: http://speedy.sh/pan48/HelloWorld.apk

Comment: i'm using Spinner and AutoCompleteTextView which uses PopupWindow. My code is as simple as examples available at developer site. But my activity is defined with `android:configChanges="orientation"`in manifest. I believe, you must be doing something else wrong which forces the display to re-create on orientation change

Comment: hmm good that you worked it out. I would suggest you to use a hardware (real phone) device besides emulator too. Because after sometimes, when your app gets bigger, emulators get slower as compare to real phones. plus a lot other benefits

Answer (score 4):

Whenever there is an orientation change, Android destroys your activity ( calls `onDestroy()`) and then restarts it (calls `onCreate()`).
As soon as your popup is up, set a flag `popup_open=1`. Your popup will naturally have a dismiss button. Set the flag=0 in the click handler of this button. You can then re-open the popup when the app restarts in the method `onRestoreInstanceState()` or in the `onCreate()`. Here you would make a check for the flag. If the flag is set to 1, bring up the popup.  So even if the orientation changed while the popup was up, `onRestoreInstanceState()` will know what to do based onthe state of the flag.
For more reference check: [How to handle runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Comment: ill assume your popup has some button for the user to dismiss it. In the click handler of this button you would have `popup_open=0`. Set `popup_open=1` as soon as your popup is launched. So if the popup is open and orientation changes, the flag wouldnt have been set to 0 and thus `onRestoreInstanceState()` should fix everything. Ill edit my answer to handle setting the flag in with the popup instead of onSaveInstanceState doing it.

Comment: yes so I was trying to say that you should set the flag in this `OnClick()` method which contains the popup object. Earlier I had suggested setting the flag in `onSaveInstanceState`.

Comment: i think youre getting confused. Why are you trying to check in onSaveInstance? As the name of this method suggests, this method is called just before destroying the app( i.e immediately after orientation change, when android is about to restart your app). You should check for the value in EITHER `onRestoreInstanceState()` OR 'onCreate()`. Have a look at the link Ive given in my answer.

Comment: its definitely possible to create a popup in oncreate. Did you declare all your objects again in oncreate? You must repeat the whole opoup creating process in your onCreate. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044093/how-to-load-popup-window-on-android-application-startup-oncreate

Answer (score 1):

Add this property to your activity in  manifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
```

and that should do it.

Comment: Some people just cannot get their hands off the downvote button, if my answer was wrong then would that person please explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

Showing PopupWindow as

```
final View parent = findViewById(R.id.{parentId});
parent.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mPopup.showAtLocation(parent, ...);
    }
});
```

resolves unhandled exception on orientation change