# In Android popup page closes forcefully when orientation changes

Tags: android

I am developing an Android Application using HTML5

i have created the one main html page and load this html page in a web view

Page works perfectly but when i want to popup page from my main html page it opens but when i change the orientation popup page closed forcefully

how to maintain the popup page remains when orientation changes

Comment: add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in activity tag in manifest

Comment: i did it but still it close the popup forcefully

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546061/how-to-keep-popup-window-opened-when-orientation-changes-at-run-time-in-android

Comment: No error just popup closed forcefully when orientation is changed because activity is recreated all the time when i changed orientation. how to stop to recreate an activity