# how to keep my popup window on orientation change?

Tags: java, android, layout, popup, android-linearlayout

I have a popup window in my activity.

Whenever I change the screen orientation to landscape, the popup disappears.

Why is that, and how can I keep the popup visible?

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        Log.i("orientation", "Orientation changed to: Landscape");
    else
        Log.i("orientation", "Orientation changed to: Portrait");
}
```

see below link for more info:-

[How to keep Popup window opened when orientation changes at run time in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546061/how-to-keep-popup-window-opened-when-orientation-changes-at-run-time-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

When orientation changes the activity will restart.. So normally the popup window calls again.. In any case if it gone try to call it within onCreate.

Or check the orientation change and take necessary recalls.

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == getResources()
                    .getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        // put some flag

         }else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != getResources()
                    .getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // change the flag

   }
```

If you put your code fragments may I can help you

Comment: but the problem is that the previous orientation still leaves

Answer (score 0):

You need to use managed Dialogs. Rather than

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.rule_edit_choose_action));
builder.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.array.dummyValues), null);
builder.show();
```

you should use something like

```
myActivity.showDialog(0);
```

and then implement onCreateDialog() in your Activity. Your activity will then manage the dialog and re-show it when you re-orientate and it's closed. If you need to change your dialog every time it is shown, implement onPrepareDialog() also - the Activity will give you access to the Dialog just before it is shown so you can update it (with a custom message, for instance).

There's lots of info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

As @Ciril said, your issue is that your Activity is restarted when you re-orientate. You could always fix your activity orientation to portrait or landscape if that is suitable for your app. That would prevent it from restarting.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you use `AlertDialog` for your popups, something along the lines of:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setTitle(R.string.popup_title);
builder.setMessage(R.string.popup_message);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // do something
    }
});
builder.show();
```

this is bad, because your `Activity` has no idea there's a popup dialog, and when you change screen orientation, the `Activity` is restarted with the new parameters, and your popup is gone.

to avoid this you'd better use `ShowDialog()` to display your popups. to make it work, you need to override `onCreateDialog()` :

```
// Called to create a dialog to be shown.
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (id) {
        case NEW_DIALOG :
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.popup_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.popup_message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

then you'd better override `onPrepareDialog()` (this is not required, actually):

```
// If a dialog has already been created, this is called
// to reset the dialog before showing it a 2nd time. Optional.
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, final Bundle bundle) {
    AlertDialog dlg = (AlertDialog) dialog;
    switch (id) {
        case NEW_DIALOG :
            dlg.SetTitle("popup title");
            // and maybe something else
    }
}
```

after all preparations you may call `ShowDialog(NEW_DIALOG)` and you Activity will remember it has a popup laid over on the top, and will recreate it after the orientation change.